# jQuery next() function is not working as expected

Tags: jquery

please check my source code

```
        $(this).next(".article").toggle();
```

or please check my whole source code here

http://jsfiddle.net/7va7jeu8/

the effect I want to achieve is when I click a title, its content (the immediate .article element under the title) will switch status ( appear or hide) ,but it seems something is wrong with my code , please help debug,Please also help clarify the reason whey it does not work. I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code to recreate the problem in the question itself.

Comment: tried to paste html code in stackoverflow several times, but the formatting always not works correctly. some codes are always hidden for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Since `hr` is immediately following the `h1` element not `article` and

*Use*

```
$(this).next() //Points to hr
       .next(".article") //
       .toggle();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/3hjz262s/)

Comment: just found perhaps using $(this).nextAll(".article").eq(0).toggle(); will be better.As I don't need to consider if there is or how many elements  in between the title <h1> and the .article element.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in jQuery API Documentation https://api.jquery.com/next/; Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

You've got hr immediately after h1 so the ".article" is not immediately after the h1

You can remove the hr node or use

```
$(this).next().next(".article").toggle();
```

Comment: better answer than mine.

Comment: Thank you Omran for the detailed explanation on the correct use of next()